# Python - File append/write does not write to file despite closing/flushing the file object

Tags: python, file-io

I have code similar to the following pseudocode:

```
def getFirstSet():
    file1 = open("log.txt", 'a')
    list1 = [item1, item2, item3, item4, ...]
    for item in list1:
         file1.write(item + '\n')
    file1.close()

def getSecondSet():
    file1 = open("log.txt", 'a')
    list1 = [item1, item2, item3, item4, ...]
    for item in list1:
         file1.write(item + '\n')
    file1.close()

getFirstSet()
getSecondSet()
```

The above is just **pseudocode** - the two functions are considerably different in the actual code - with different outputs/parsing and purpose.

The issue I have is that the first function executes properly and the desired items are written to the file. The second function executes, and no errors are returned, however no content is written through the second function. I understand there are issues with buffering that are solved by either flushing or closing the file in question, however code fails either way. Would anyone have any idea why this might happen? Is there some concept I'm missing?

I also need to have the code append to the existing file, not overwrite (hence the usage of 'a' instead of 'w'.
(Python 3, Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `with open() as outfile:`  with 'w'. Samlple code is:

```
def getFirstSet():
    with open("log.txt", 'w') as file1:
        list1 = [item1, item2, item3, item4, ...]
        for item in list1:
            file1.write(item + '\n')
    
   
    

def getSecondSet():
    with open("log.txt", 'w') as file1:
        list1 = [item1, item2, item3, item4, ...]
        for item in list1:
             file1.write(item + '\n')

getFirstSet()
getSecondSet()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the file in Write.

```
file1 = open("log.txt", 'w')
```

Just curious, why do you need too identical functions?

Comment: Edited original post; the code above is just pseudocode - the two actual functions I have vary in purpose; they are obtaining different things to write to the file (the file itself is a text file I'm creating to monitor a separate process).

Comment: oh i see. just curious.

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to add a colon(:) in function, e.g. `def getFirstSet():` I think that's why it's not working.

The above code, you can write using one function for good practice.

```
def writeContent(file):
    file1 = open(file, 'a')
    list1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]
    for item in list1:
         file1.write(item + '\n')
    file1.close()

writeContent("log.txt")
writeContent("log.txt")
```

You can also pass the item list when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution; I'm unsure why this works but using a context manager with the file opened and closed outside of the calling functions seems to fix this issue. The only difference is the file is only closed and opened once as opposed to twice.

```
def getFirstSet(file1):
    list1 = [item1, item2, item3, item4, ...]
    for item in list1:
        file1.write(item + '\n')
    file1.close()

def getSecondSet(file1):
    list1 = [item1, item2, item3, item4, ...]
    for item in list1:
        file1.write(item + '\n')
    file1.close()

with open("log.txt", "a") as file1:
    getFirstSet(file1)
    getSecondSet(file1)
```